# Bulk rename files and folders, stripping all spaces from the name to underscore in Windows

Tags: windows, script, rename, filenames, bulk

I want to do this as in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11278987/7492158), but I need to remove all spaces with underscores, also folders and files, but when i put in a root of a folder I want it to go through all subfolders and files.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Assume you meant 'replace' all spaces with underscores...

in PS `Get-ChildItems` or `gci` is pretty powerful

```
 > gci -r -n
   Silly Windows
   Silly Windows\empty file2
   Silly Windows\emptyfile1

 > gci -r | where-object { $_.name.Contains(" ") } | rename-item -NewName { $_.name -replace " ","" }

 > gci -r -n
   SillyWindows
   SillyWindows\emptyfile1
   SillyWindows\emptyfile2
```

Comment: Thank you, I meant rename, is it possible to make a .bat file so that i don't need to use powershell? Because, a lot of users is going to use this script

Comment: any reason why you couldn't stick it in a bat/cmd file

Comment: I dont know how to do that, that's why I've asked is there some script like in the link I've provided. I've used in powershell "cmd.exe /C srcipt_name.bat" but it's not working, and it doesnt' replace space with _ only remove spaces!